# A question about fields and separability in Serre's "Local Fields"

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, local-field

On page 14 of the English edition of Serre's "Local Fields", that is chapter 1, section 4, I am confused by the following; there is talk of **fields** $B/\mathfrak P$ and $A/\mathfrak p$ for prime ideals $\mathfrak P$ of a ring $B$ and $\mathfrak p$ of a ring $A.$ Surely that would require $\mathfrak P$ and $\mathfrak p$ to be maximal ideals? Also in the next paragraph there is talk of the extension $B/\mathfrak P$ of $A/\mathfrak p$ being **separable**, which is a concept I know only for field extensions. So how should I interpret all of this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Separability can be defined for arbitrary extensions of commutativ rings, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right before that he says

> Let us keep the hypotheses of prop. 9. If $\mathfrak{P}$ is a non-zero prime ideal of $B$...

Proposition 9 says

> **Proposition 9.** If $A$ is Dedekind then $B$ is Dedekind.

and in a Dedekind domain, every non-zero prime ideal is maximal. Thus $\mathfrak{P}$ and $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{P}\cap A$ are indeed maximal, and thus $B/\mathfrak{P}$ and $A/\mathfrak{p}$ are indeed fields.

---

But I'll also note that there is a notion of separability for ring extensions; see *[The Separable Galois Theory of Commutative Rings](https://www.crcpress.com/The-Separable-Galois-Theory-of-Commutative-Rings-Second-Edition/Magid/9781482208054)* for example.

Comment: Indeed! I succeeded to miss the keeping of hypotheses, which clear up everything. Thank you and sorry for the quite idiotic question.